# Search for a file content in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-controller

Hi I'm writing a c# code where in there is a string sent as a parameter input to the method. And then the inputString has to be searched in the file and the result has to be returned. Currently I know how do I do this in the regular way(using the file IO).

```
[HttpPost]
        public string UsernameValidation(string username)
        {
            string text = username;
            string userExists = usernameNotAvailable;
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("~/UserData/usernameslist.txt");

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(text))
                {
                    userExists = usernameAvailable;
                }

            }
            return userExists;
        }
```

But here is the twist, my project is in MVC. I'm able to get the path of file using `string userDataFile = Server.MapPath("~/UserData/usernameslist.txt");`.

But I'm unable to know how can I get the functionality of searching a string in a file.

Please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the the file *usernameslist.txt* really exists inside a subfolder named *UserData* from your root folder then you just need to pass the output of Server.MapPath to your StreamReader constructor

```
string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/UserData/usernameslist.txt");

using(StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName))
{
    ....
}
```

And don't forget to use the *using statement* around a Stream object

Comment: Thank you soo much Steve. :)